# How do I use the exported 'best.pt" file from yolov5 colab file to run the trained weights locally?

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolov5

I have trained my model using yoloV5 on google colab, following the provided tutorial and walkthrough provided for training any custom model: [Colab file for training your own custom model](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gDZ2xcTOgR39tGGs-EZ6i3RTs16wmzZQ). I now have an exported `best.pt` file after running the last cell in the link provided. Now, I want to make use of this trained weight to run a detection locally on any python script. Is this possible? If so, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow this step:

- Create an empty folder in desktop called **ObjectDetection**
- Open command prompt and change directory to that new folder using
  `cd ObjectDetection`.
- Clone yolov5 repo using command - `git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5.git`. It will create a new folder called **yolov5** inside **ObjectDetection** folder.
  **yolov5** folder contains important python file called **detect.py** which is responsible to detect the objects.
- After cloning the repo, enter into yolov5 folder using `cd yolov5`
- Install all the necessary requirements using - `pip install -r requirements.txt`
- Download **best.pt** from colab and manually paste it inside **yolov5** folder.
- Also copy the image that you want to test inside **yolov5** folder.
- Before running inference, make sure that **image.png, best.pt and detect.py** should be in inside **yolov5** folder.
- You can then run inference inside **yolov5** folder by using this command:
  `python detect.py --weights best.pt --source image.png`
- After the process is completed, you can check the result inside path `ObjectDetection/yolov5/runs/detect/exp`

Comment: Okay when I run the install step, I get an error for building wheel for pycocotools. How do I fix that? Or do I ignore the error

Comment: Are you using windows or linux?

Comment: Use this command separately `pip3 install pycocotools`

Answer (score 0):

Use colab files lib

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('/content/yolov5/runs/train/yolov5s_results/weights/best.pt')
```

If the path is different you can change the path.